# How to get AWS MediaLive channel alerts using .Net SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, aws-media-live

I'm trying to list the alerts that's showing for a running channel on MediaLive on my C# GUI using the .NET SDK

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqVAu.png)

I've attempted to use the MediaLiveClient to do this, and have called the DescribeChannel function, however although it offers me an option to see, the piplines running, channel status etc. It does not have a way for my to retrieve the alerts.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/MediaLive/TDescribeChannelResponse.html

Is there another way to get these alerts?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post.

To get the active alerts, you can configure a CloudWatch event to propagate selected service alerts to an SNS Topic which can be polled by various clients including a Lambda function, which can then take various actions on your behalf. This approach works well to aggregate the alerts from multiple channels or services [1].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/monitoring-via-cloudwatch.html